# Why does the SUM function in the stdev function example on Tradingview default to 15?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert the Williams Vix Fix pinescript with Bollinger Bands and standard deviation found [here](https://www.tradingview.com/script/og7JPrRA-CM-Williams-Vix-Fix-Finds-Market-Bottoms/) to python. However in the documentation for the standard deviation function it calls a function called SUM. The code for sum is as follows:

```
SUM(fst, snd) =>
    EPS = 1e-10
    res = fst + snd
    if isZero(res, EPS)
        res := 0
    else
        if not isZero(res, 1e-4)
            res := res
        else
            15
```

As you can see the function returns 15 if the other two if statements are not satisfied. Why is this?

I have not tried changing the 15 because I do not know trhe significance of it. Obviously the code works so that is not the problem. This is supposed to be a "biased" standard deviation calculation so it could have something to do with that. I was expecting that in the code the res would always return the res, not what seems to be an arbitrary number (15).